# Create associative array from foreach values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to create associative array from foreach loop.

```
    if (sizeof($ads) > 0) {
    foreach($ads as $social_item) {
        $sdbr .= $social_item['sidebar'];
        $pno .= $social_item['no']; 
       }
       echo $sdbr // cow hen
       echo $pno  // milk egg
    }
```

How can I create associative array like this one?

```
$out = array("cow"=>"milk","hen"=>"egg");
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if you do this, any duplicate values of 'sidebar' will be overwritten in the `$out` array. It will end up with only the last associated 'no' value.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: In this example the only other things I can think of are `cow=>steak,hen=>breast`

Comment: No problem, the value of sidebar and no values are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sidebar` as the key and `no` as the value:

```
foreach($ads as $social_item) {
    $sdbr = $social_item['sidebar'];
    $pno  = $social_item['no'];
    $out[$sdbr] = $pno;
   }
}
print_r($out);
```

If you still need the strings:

```
foreach($ads as $social_item) {
    $sdbr .= $social_item['sidebar'];
    $pno  .= $social_item['no'];
    $out[$social_item['sidebar']] = $social_item['no'];
   }
   echo $sdbr // cow hen
   echo $pno  // milk egg
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . Really saved my day.